# Iphone 5 jquery modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I have a prob that i think is common on iPhone devices. I have a jquery modal dialog popup and when i scroll on this modal and touch on a select element after touching the done button is scrolls me to the top. By default my modal position is fixed. I found an article that says if you change it to position absolute it will be fixed but actually it does not. Please find below my code and give some help guys. Thanks

```
    j('.modal input[type=text], .modal select').each(function () {
    if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
        var osVar = new UAParser().getOS();

        var verticalPos = "";
        if (osVar == "iOS") {

            j(this).on('focus', function (e) {
                verticalPos = j(this).offset().top;
                j('.modal').css("position", "absolute");
            });

            j(this).on('blur', function (e) {
                j('.modal').css("position", "fixed");
                j(this).scrollTop(verticalPos);

            });
        }
    }
});
```